# Committing a commit hook in git

Tags: git

Commit hooks in git live in the .git/hooks directory. What I would love is be able to commit those hooks so everyone checking out the repo has the hooks automatically. I'm not able to add the files inside .git/hooks to git however. Is this not at all possible?

I do realise there are server side hooks by the way, this is a theoretical quest :)

Comment: IMO that would introduce a security concern - people cloning your repo would get code executed without their knowledge. Rather, I suggest something not 10^2% automatic: commit the hooks to the repo itself and write a script to put (copy or move) the hooks in place. Of course it still requires you to instruct contributors to run that script by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, all you can do is have the hooks in the repo if needed and ask the owner of the repo to copy them to the `.git/hooks` ( or have another script in the repo that will copy the hooks ( or create symlink to them) , change permission etc. when it is run )

Comment: Or symlink them, like we do with phpBB: https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/tree/develop/git-tools/hooks

Comment: @igorw - thanks, forgot about symlink which is what I do, lol :)

Comment: Thanks, I will then proceed to write a script which generates symlinks indeed.